# How do I enable multisampling (antialiasing) in OpenGL with Qt5?

Tags: opengl, qt5, multisampling

How do I enable multisampling when I create the window? How should I initialize OpenGL to match?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this one out.

The trick is to use a `QSurfaceFormat` in your `QWindow`'s constructor like so:

```
setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(4);    // Set the number of samples used for multisampling
setFormat(format);       // Note we set the format on the window...
create();                // Create the window

context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
context->setFormat(format);    // ...and set the format on the context too
context->create();
```

And later, when initialising OpenGL:

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);    // This seems to be the default given the configuration above, but just in case that's not universal...
```

Comment: really strange, what is the point in setting it on the QOpenGLContext if QWindow will just do its own thing

Comment: @paulm: No idea, I just fiddled with stuff until it worked ;-)